# Сохранить все элементы, вводимые в поле, в коллекции

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте! Пишу сайт на asp.net.
Создала коллекцию

```
ArrayList newMail = new ArrayList();
```

Есть текстовое поле

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вводимый текст сохранялся в коллекции?
Пробовала так:

```
ArrayList newMail = new ArrayList();
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string eMail = TextBox1.Text;
    newMail.Insert(NewMail.Count, eMail);
    for (int i = 0; i < newMail.Count; i++)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(newMail[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Но в результате я всегда получаю коллекцию из одного элемента, последнего... А мне нужно, чтобы все элементы, вводимые в текстовое поле сохранялись в коллекции.

Comment: Для начала, почему `ArrayList`? Это ж позапрошлый век. Пользуйтесь `List<string>`. Затем, а где у вас хранится ваш `newMail`? Внутри какого-то класса — какого именно? Не пересоздаётся ли этот объект каждый раз?

Comment: Да, в этом и проблема, что он пересоздает объект...
Мне казалось, что я нашла решение:
const string vsKey = "myVSKey";
    ArrayList newMail
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState[vsKey] == null) ViewState[vsKey] = new ArrayList();
            return ViewState[vsKey] as ArrayList;
        }
        set { ViewState[vsKey] = value; }
    }

Comment: В пробной проге все работало, но когда я вставила это в проект, опять таже ерунда, он постоянно пересоздает объект... Как от этого избавиться? Пробовала использовать List<string>, но возникли проблемы с синтаксисом (я только начинаю программировать) и в итоге в инете вычитала про ArrayList...

Comment: @Juli174: А что это за объект? Если этот объект должен создаваться каждый раз, возможно, вы должны разместить `newMail` в каком-то другом месте. расскажите подробнее про семантику: какова область жизни/применения `newMail`. Соединение? Сессия? Весь сайт?

Comment: Есть кнопка, нажимая на которую появляется текстовое поле, пользователь вводит email, делается валидация, если все хорошо, то email записывается в бд, текстовое поле становится невидным, а на его месте появляется Label с названием email'а. Получается динамическое добавление email'ов.
newMail содержит коллекцию всех валидных email'ов, введенных пользователем. Скорее всего срок жизни newMail - пока не перезагрузится вся страница (обновление email'ов расположено в UpdatePanel, ScriptManager). Хотя возможно срок жизни - вся работа сайта, но это навряд ли.))

Comment: @Juli174, ну так чтобы срок жизни контейнера не зависил от roundtrip'ов, используйте холдер.

Comment: простите, если сейчас натуплю, но:

    newMail.Insert(NewMail.Count, eMail);

разве newMail и NewMail это не разные вещи? Тогда он и будет каждый раз один и тот же индекс использовать.

Comment: @Макс Жуков, если честно, то у меня не получилось применить Ваш код к своему проекту. Выдавалась ошибка. Компилятор не воспринимал класс holder. Не знаю с чем это связано... Может нужно дополнительную библиотеку подключить?
Я первый раз услышала про holder. Если возможно, скиньте, пожалуйста, ссылку, чтобы про него почитать.

Comment: @Fike, если бы это были разные вещи, то компилятор выдал бы ошибку, потому что объявлена только одна коллекция))

Comment: @Juli174, я бы все-таки проверил их одинаковость в дебаггере. Сишарп - регистрозависимый язык.

Comment: @Juli174, класс вы можете назвать как угодно. Смысл в том, что у вас есть статический объект, доступный из любой части приложения вне зависимости от lifecycle веб-страницы. И, кстати, очень может быть что @Fike прав.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, вы каждый раз инициализируете новый массив `newMail`.

Сделайте холдер для этой коллекции:

```
public static class Holder
{
    private ArrayList _list = new ArrayList();

    public ArrayList MailList
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set { _list = value; }
    }
}
```

И работайте с ним:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string eMail = TextBox1.Text;
   Holder.MailList.Insert(NewMail.Count, eMail);
   for (int i = 0; i < newMail.Count; i++)
   {
      ListBox1.Items.Add(Holder.MailList[i].ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, этот вариант не срабатывает(((

Comment: @Juli174, что значит не срабатывает? записываются ли элементы в коллекцию? сохраняются или нет? прогоните в дебаггере...

Comment: элементы не записываются, в коллекции постоянно только один элемент - последний записанный(( Возможно, это я неправильно что-то делаю. 
Я уже нашла решение. Спасибо, что ответили.)) 
Если Вам интересно, могу написать решение.)))